# Can I ask conference chair to give me an early result?

Tags: conference, paper-submission

I have submitted a paper in one of the top conferences in our field (IEEE Globecom 2018). Now, since this was my first time, I submitted to the symposium and now I realize that there are Workshops coming in as well. After submission of my paper, now that it is nearly 4+ months and I have written (and submitted) two journal articles. I realize the "written" quality of the Conference paper is not good and I am afraid it might get a rejection for this reason.

Can I ask the conf. chair to give me an early result so that I can submit the same paper in the Workshop with improvements?

conf (symposium) acceptance notification with come on 15th July.
Workshop submission deadline: 14th July.

Comment: If the deadline is July 14 AoE, you might just receive the notification in time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly ask, but you should not expect or demand an answer. Conference organizers may have hundreds of abstracts they may need to sort through and it may not be possible to give you an answer until the notification date.

Comment: While you might get a negative result early you are unlikely to get a positive one before the listed date. That may be what you need, of course. But a committee process may winnow out many of the papers relatively quickly and spend most of its time on a smaller set of the (perceived) best papers. But even then, not everything can be accepted. Some committees work by asking members to "champion" one or two papers in the final decision rounds. It is possible, of course, that the dates were chosen precisely to prevent re-submission to the workshop. If so, your request will not be honored.

Comment: In this field (and this conference in particular), it's not an abstract, it's a full paper that goes through peer review by a very large technical program committee. So it's highly unlikely that they'll have an answer just because the reviews probably haven't come in yet.

Comment: @ff524 The reviews aren’t in less than a week before the notification deadline? That really happens?

Comment: @aeismail actually, in my experience with many conferences in this field, the reviews come in late and notifications often end up coming days or  weeks *after* the notification deadline...